# Copy all .csv files in directory to .xlsx files in another directory, Traceback error

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm working on this script that first takes all .csv's and converts them .xlsx's in a separate folder. I'm getting the first file to output exactly how I want in the 'Script files' folder, but then it throws a Traceback error before it does the second one.

Script code below, Traceback error below that. Some path data removed for privacy:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

# Assign current directory and list files there
f_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
rd_path = f_path+'\\Raw Data'
sc_path = f_path+'\\Script files'

# Create /Script files folder

if os.path.isdir(sc_path) == False:
    os.mkdir(sc_path)
    print("\nCreating new Script files path here...",sc_path)
else:
    print("\nScript files directory exists!")

# List files in Raw Data directory
print("\nRaw Data files in the directory:\n",rd_path,"\n")

for filename in os.listdir(rd_path):
    f = os.path.join(rd_path,filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(filename)
print("\n\n\n")

# Copy and edit data files to /Script files folder
for filename in os.listdir(rd_path):
    src = os.path.join(rd_path,filename)
    if os.path.isfile(src):
        name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        read_file = pd.read_csv(src)
        result = sc_path+"\\"+name+'.xlsx'
        read_file.to_excel(result)
        print(src,"\nconverted and written to: \n",result,"\n\n")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\_________________\Graph.py", line 32, in <module>
    read_file = pd.read_csv(src)
  File "C:\Users\_____________\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\______________\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\_____________\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 581, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\_____________\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1250, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\_____________\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 225, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 805, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1960, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 47, saw 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to convert to xlsx the second file in the folder? I'm not sure but it seems like there's a problem when Pandas reads the csv.

Comment: Yes it does look like the error occurs when it tries to read the .csv. But this code successfully reads and converts the first file, then errors out on the second one. I can't figure out why

Comment: I'd put the code around a try / except block to see if it works on the rest of the csv files.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out this issue was due to the formatting of my 2nd .csv file. Opening it up, I had a number of cells above the data I wanted. After deleting these extra rows so that the relevant data started in row 1, the code ran correctly. Looks like I'll have to add code to detect these extra rows and delete them prior to attempting to convert to .xlsx.